# How can I pass a List of graphics.py Points as an argument to Polygon()?

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I'm working on a simple program to draw a house using Python 3.6 and Zelle's graphics.py.
I'm using Notepad++ as an editor.

I've fulfilled all the requirements for my assignment, but there is a stipulation that if scenery is added, bonus marks can be earned. I initially wanted to add smoke coming out of the chimney of the house I drew.

I tried creating a list of Points, which looked something like this:

```
    Smoke = []
    for i in range(1, 30):
        Smoke.append(Point(554 + i, i**2 / 3))
    for j in range(31, 80):
        Smoke.append(Point(554 + j, Smoke[j - 1] + 100 / j))
    for k in range(79, -1, -1)
        Smoke.append(Smoke[k])
```

The problem with this is that I wanted to change the 'y' parameter of Smoke[k] before appending it, so I decided to create two lists:

```
    SmokeX = []
    SmokeY = []
    for i in range (1, 30):
        SmokeX.append(Point(554 + i))
        SmokeY.append(Point(i**2 / 3))
    for j in range (31, 80):
        SmokeX.append(Point(554 + j))
        SmokeY.append(Point(SmokeY[j - 1] + 100 / j))
    for k in range (79, -1, -1):
        SmokeX.append(Point(554 + k))
        SmokeY.append(Point(SmokeY[k] + 50))
```

Those who aren't looking at this at 01:00 AM like I was, will have recognized that my two lists are literally pointless (pun intended), since they don't have two parameters. Since I can't set either parameter as NULL, I abandoned this approach.

Finally, I tried to store just numbers, instead of Points, in the vague hope that Polygon() will accept these. I have since opened graphics.py and discovered that Polygon() is a very strict overlord, and will take only Points as arguments, and not numbers. This is my full house.py file for reference.

```
    from graphics import *
    from math import *

    def main():

        #Initialization
        win = GraphWin("House", 800, 800)

        win.setBackground(color_rgb(191, 191, 191))

        #Main House
        HouseBody = Rectangle(Point(100, 300), Point(700, 700))
        HouseBody.setFill(color_rgb(96, 96, 96))

        #Roof
        HouseRoof = Polygon(Point(100, 300), Point(700, 300), Point(400, 200))
        HouseRoof.setFill(color_rgb(255, 127, 0))

        #Windows
        HouseWindowLeft = Circle(Point(200, 450), 60)
        HouseWindowLeft.setFill(color_rgb(0, 191, 255))
        HouseWindowLeftBarV = Rectangle(Point(198, 390), Point(202, 510))
        HouseWindowLeftBarV.setFill(color_rgb(0, 0, 0))
        HouseWindowLeftBarH = Rectangle(Point(140, 448), Point(260, 452))
        HouseWindowLeftBarH.setFill(color_rgb(0, 0, 0))

        HouseWindowRight = Circle(Point(600, 450), 60)
        HouseWindowRight.setFill(color_rgb(0, 191, 255))
        HouseWindowRightBarV = Rectangle(Point(598, 390), Point(602, 510))
        HouseWindowRightBarV.setFill(color_rgb(0, 0, 0))
        HouseWindowRightBarH = Rectangle(Point(540, 448), Point(660, 452))
        HouseWindowRightBarH.setFill(color_rgb(0, 0, 0))

        #Door

        HouseDoor = Rectangle(Point(350, 500), Point(450, 700))
        HouseDoor.setFill(color_rgb(255, 0, 0))
        HouseDoorKnob = Circle(Point(440, 630), 5)
        HouseDoorKnob.setFill(color_rgb(0, 0, 0))

        #Chimney

        HouseChimney = Polygon(Point(550, 250), Point (550, 200), Point(600, 200), Point(600, 267))
        HouseChimney.setFill(color_rgb(0, 127, 127))

        #Additional Scenery - Smoke

        SmokeX = []
        SmokeY = []
        for i in range (1, 30):
            SmokeX.append(554 + i)
            SmokeY.append(i**2 / 3)
        for j in range (31, 80):
            SmokeX.append(554 + j)
            SmokeY.append(SmokeY[j - 1] + 100 / j)
        for k in range (79, -1, -1):
            SmokeX.append(554 + k)
            SmokeY.append(SmokeY[k] + 50)

        HouseSmoke = Polygon(SmokeX, SmokeY)
        HouseSmoke.setFill(color_rgb(255, 255, 255))

        #Drawing to Screen
        HouseBody.draw(win)
        HouseRoof.draw(win)
        HouseWindowLeft.draw(win)
        HouseWindowLeftBarV.draw(win)
        HouseWindowLeftBarH.draw(win)
        HouseWindowRight.draw(win)
        HouseWindowRightBarV.draw(win)
        HouseWindowRightBarH.draw(win)
        HouseDoor.draw(win)
        HouseDoorKnob.draw(win)
        HouseChimney.draw(win)
        HouseSmoke.draw(win)

        win.getMouse()
        win.close()

    main()
```

Currently I am also getting an out-of-bounds index error, although I can probably resolve that on my own. I'm now genuinely curious how I could generate a list[] of Points and then pass them to Polygon() in order to draw a shape using graphics.py. Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your Smoke loop this way, spreading your list of Points as the arguments to Polygon()

```
Smoke = []
for i in range(1, 30):
    Smoke.append(Point(554 + i, i**2 / 3))
for j in range(29, 80):
    Smoke.append(Point(554 + j, Smoke[j - 1].getY() + 100 / j))
for k in range(79, -1, -1):
    Smoke.append(Point(554 + k, Smoke[k].getY() + 50))

HouseSmoke = Polygon(*Smoke)
```

Your indexing problem is here:

```
for i in range (1, 30):
    ...
    SmokeY.append(i**2 / 3)
```

This creates index locations 0 - 28 in array SmokeY (range is 1 to 29 but arrays start at 0).  But the next clause tries to access index location 30 in SmokeY which doesn't exist (nor does 29):

```
for j in range (31, 80):
    ...
    SmokeY.append(SmokeY[j - 1] + 100 / j)
```

You need to be more careful in  accounting for your array indexes.